# Address in mailbox given [$to_name,$to_email] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2

Tags: laravel

i get that error here is my store function am trying to send mail to that email

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $to_name = 'TO_NAME';
    $to_email = 'TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS';
    $data = array('name'=>"Sam Jose", "body" => "Test mail");
    Mail::send('layouts.mail', $data, function($message) use ($to_name,$to_email) {
        $message->to('$to_name,$to_email');
        $message->subject('Booking Enquiry');
        $message->from('kisilamapeni@gmail.com','kisila');
    });
    echo "Email sent";
}
```

Comment: What is `TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS` and `TO_NAME` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want variable parsed from string, you have to use `"` instead of `'`

```php
$message->to("$to_name, $to_email");
```

In Laravel's `Illuminate/Mail/Message` method `to` has three arguments, and email address is first

https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Mail/Message.html#method_to

So, you should in general omit your quotes:

```php
$message->to($to_email, $to_name);
```

Comment: still getting same problem  Swift_RfcComplianceException
Address in mailbox given [kisilamapeni] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.

Comment: seems like you are trying to add name as email argument. ensure you have correct argument order